# Hide Bootstrap sub menus on mobiles

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, hide

I am using a nav walker to enable drop down menus using bootstrap in Wordpress, and it all works fine. What I am trying to figure out is there a way to disable the drop downs on mobiles, perhaps using media queries?

The reason I want to do this is because there are a lot of pages and some links are on a 3rd tier which flies off the mobile screen. The top level navigation have links to the sub menu items anyway, so in mobiles I would like to just have the top level items shown, and disable the sub menus from being displayed.

Also I am not using the nav collapse with icons, as I didnt want to use it on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it can be done by Media Queries. This one targets mobile devices:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
    .navigation {display:none;}
}
```

Of course, you will have to keep an eye out for the sizes of the screens now days. One alternative solution would be in JavaScript, and check the userAgent:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android|BlackBerry|webOS|Windows Phone)/i)) {
    // I'm a mobile :-)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Eric, using your snippet it worked and I used: @media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
display: none;
}
}